# while inside foreach kills original array

Tags: perl, foreach, while-loop

For some reason my original array gets wiped out with this code. I can't figure out why? @my_array is empty after running this, I took out all the work in the while loop to see if that was the cause but its not.

```
foreach (@my_array)
{
    open MY_FH, "<", $_;
    while (<MY_FH>)
        {
        }
    close MY_FH;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not empty, it's just full of `undef`.

`while (<MY_FH>)` is syntactic sugar for `while (defined($_ = <MY_FH>))`.  Since the variable in a `foreach` loop is an alias to the original value, the filename in `$_` gets overwritten with each line of the file.  The `while` loop keeps going until `<MY_FH>` returns `undef` to indicate EOF.  That `undef` is the last value stored in `$_`.

The solution is to use a different variable in at least one of the loops.  Changing the `foreach` loop will probably be less work:

```
foreach my $fn (@my_array)
{
    open MY_FH, "<", $fn;
    while (<MY_FH>)
        {
        }
    close MY_FH;
}
```

If you checked the size of `@my_array` after the loop with `scalar @my_array`, you'd find that it hasn't changed.  But an array of `undef` looks just like an empty array when you're accessing individual elements, which is probably why you think it's empty.

Comment: Note: while `foreach (@array)` does an implicit `local $_`, `while (<FH>)` does not.

Answer (score 0):

As cjm has explained, the elements of the array are overwritten by the `while` loop because it reads from the file into `$_`, which the `foreach` aliases to each array element in turn

The simplest solution is to *localise* `$_` for the duration of the `while` loop. That creates a temporary copy of `$_` that can be used without affecting  `@my_array`. Like this

```
for ( @my_array ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $_;

    local $_;    # To protect @my_array

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        ...
    }
    close $fh;
}
```